# I want to use the indexes I got from enumerate() for slicing the word. I can't find how to do it

Tags: python, slice, enumeration

I am working with a word which is input by the user. Example: "where". I need to find the first vowel and start the word from it, and place the beginning of the word to the end.

First I want to understand indexes of each letter and I did it with enumerate():
Now I want to get the index of a vowel and make the word sliced.

The question is how to pass to python the information about the indices I got from enumerate and how to make it define the index of the vowel?

I found lots of tutorials on slicing, but still did not get how to unite these two functions.
Please help me (maybe you know a tutorial which can help or just give ideas).
I am a beginner, so keep it simple, please.
I am stuck, I don't understand how to iterate through the word/words and at the same time get its index.

Comment: Please clarify by showing the output you expect and the problem you have with your current code (which you seem to have forgotten to post)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following:

```
word = 'where'
i_vowel = 0
for index, char in enumerate(word):
    if char in "aeiou":
        i_vowel = index
        break
word = word[i_vowel:]+word[0:i_vowel]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use enumerate to "walk" the string. This gives you the index (subscript) and character at the corresponding position. Then a simple slice will  give the output you need.

```
VOWELS = set('aeiouAEIOU')

s = 'where'

for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c in VOWELS:
        print(f'{s[i:]}{s[:i]}')
        break
```

**Output:**

```
erewh
```

Answer (score -1):

```
word = 'where'
vowels = "aeiou"

for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter in vowels:
        i_word = word[i:] + word[:i]
        break

print(i_word)
```